# Adobe AIR 1.5 Sandbox + Motherboard Speaker

Tags: audio, frameworks, air, sandbox

I'm curious if through AIR you could access your motherboard pc speaker?

It's for an Alarm Type of program and would like pitch control so more than a simple beep. Can this be accomplished through AIR?

Or if not in any web-based framework for that matter? Seems a  bit tricky so I'd love to know if anyone has a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into it and I don't think it's possible. AIR runs at an application level, and although some system resources are available, most aren't.